# Why won't YUI Compressor munge these function names?

Tags: yui-compressor, minify

This is the input:

```
function local2functionA()
{
    local2functionB('hello');
}

function local2functionB(text)
{
    alert(text);
}
```

This is the output:

```
function local2functionA(){local2functionB("hello")}function local2functionB(a){alert(a)};
```

Any ideas where it hasn't munged the function names?

Same outcome at http://www.shrinker.ch/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because those functions are declared on the top-level, and thus visible to the "outside" so you cannot just change their name.

If you put the definition of local2functionB inside of local2functionA, it minifies nicely:

```
function local2functionA()
{
    function local2functionB(text)
    {
      alert(text);
    }

    local2functionB('hello');
}

// becomes 

function local2functionA(){alert("hello")};
```

Note that the remaining top-level function also does not get renamed (while the "private" function gets inlined away completely).

Comment: Ah yes, that'll be it.  I get this when I run it through YUI:

function local2functionA(){function a(b){alert(b)}a("hello")};